# get audio to play on A-frame ios vr

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, aframe, virtual-reality

so i have an A-frame scene setup everything works as expected except ios mobile. i need the music file to play when the cursor hovers over a plane. so far i have achieved this using a registerComponent technique. i am quite new to a-frame so dont know too much about it. i know ios needs a proper user interaction but ive tried all sorts and just cant get it to play at all on ios. im open to different methods / work around as well. the reason im calling a js function is because im more comfortable with that and know how to control audio better. essentially what i need is when a user gazes over 1 of the 3 thumbnails it changes the scene image and plays a song but stops other audio currently playing so audio dosent overlap.

here is my code

```
 <script id="plane" type="text/html">
 <a-entity class="link"
 geometry="primitive: plane; height: 1; width: 1"
 material="shader: flat; src: ${thumb}; transparent:true;"
 event-set__mouseenter="scale: 1.2 1.2 1"
event-set__mouseleave="scale: 1 1 1"
event-set__click="_target: #image-360; _delay: 300; material.src: ${src}"
proxy-event="event: click; to: #image-360; as: fade"
sound="on: click; src: #click-sound"
 >

 </a-entity>
 </script>

  </head>


 <body>




 <a-scene class="scene">
<div onclick="void(0);">
<div class="intro-outer-wrapper">
  <div class="intro-inner-wrapper">
  <div class="enter-button">ENTER</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<a-assets>


  <!-- Audio files-->
  <audio  id="click-sound" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/360-image-gallery- 
   boilerplate/audio/click.ogg"></audio>
  <audio id="city-bgm" src="assets/audio/song1.mp3"></audio>
  <audio id="blocks-bgm" src="assets/audio/song2.mp3"></audio>
  <audio tid="beach-bgm" src="assets/audio/song3.mp3"></audio>


  <!-- Images. use use for background and thumbs -->
  <img id="city" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/360-image-gallery- 
   boilerplate/img/city.jpg">
  <img id="city-thumb" src="assets/thumb4.svg">
  <img id="cubes" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/360-image-gallery- 
   boilerplate/img/cubes.jpg">
  <img id="cubes-thumb" src="assets/thumb3.svg">
  <img id="sechelt" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/360-image-gallery- 
   boilerplate/img/sechelt.jpg">
  <img id="sechelt-thumb" src="assets/thumb2.svg">
</a-assets>


<!-- 360-degree background image. -->
<a-sky id="image-360" radius="10" src="#city"
animation__fade="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; from: 
#FFF; to: #000; dur: 300; startEvents: fade"
animation__fadeback="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; from: 
#000; to: #FFF; dur: 300; startEvents: animationcomplete__fade">
</a-sky>


<!-- clickable thumbnails with functions. -->

 <a-entity id="links" >
<a-entity look-at="#camera" position="-6 0 -4" template="src: #plane" data- 
  src="#city" data-thumb="#city-thumb" play_sound_1 ></a-entity>
 <a-entity look-at="#camera" position="-6 0 0" template="src: #plane" data- 
 src="#cubes" data-thumb="#cubes-thumb" play_sound_2 ></a-entity>
<a-entity  look-at="#camera" position="-6 0 4" template="src: #plane" data- 
 src="#sechelt" data-thumb="#sechelt-thumb " play_sound_3 ></a-entity>
 </a-entity>
 <!-- Camera + cursor. -->
 <a-entity id="camera"camera look-controls>
  <a-cursor
  id="cursor"
  animation__click="property: scale; startEvents: click; from: 0.1 0.1 0.1; to: 1 1 1; dur: 1500"
  animation__fusing="property: fusing; startEvents: fusing; from: 1 1 1; to: 0.1 0.1 0.1; dur: 1500"
  event-set__mouseenter="_event: mouseenter; color: springgreen"
  event-set__mouseleave="_event: mouseleave; color: black"
  raycaster="objects: .link"></a-cursor>
  </a-entity>

   </a-scene>




  <script>


 var song1 = document.getElementById("city-bgm");
 var song2 = document.getElementById("blocks-bgm");
 var song3 = document.getElementById("beach-bgm");


 // slide intro up


  $('.enter-button').on('touchstart click', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
   $(".intro-outer-wrapper").fadeOut(500);

   });


    // play song 1 on thumbnail1 click
    AFRAME.registerComponent('play_sound_1', {


    init: function () {

   var el = this.el;

   el.addEventListener('click', function () {
   console.log("mouse enter")
   song1.play()
   song2.pause()
   song3.pause()
   song2.currentTime = 0;
  song3.currentTime = 0;
  });


  }


  });

  // play song 2 on thumbnail1 click
 AFRAME.registerComponent('play_sound_2', {


  init: function () {

   var el = this.el;

   el.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log("mouse enter")
   song2.play()
   song1.pause()
   song3.pause()
   song1.currentTime = 0;
  song3.currentTime = 0;
   });


    }


   });

   // play song 3 on thumbnail1 click
    AFRAME.registerComponent('play_sound_3', {


   init: function () {

   var el = this.el;

   el.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log("mouse enter")
  song3.play()
  song2.pause()
  song1.pause()
  song2.currentTime = 0;
  song1.currentTime = 0;
   });


   }


    });


    AFRAME.registerComponent('look-at', {
   schema: { type: 'selector' },

    init: function () {},

     tick: function () {
   this.el.object3D.lookAt(this.data.object3D.position)
   }
   })
   </script>
```

any help would be very welcome.

Comment: i have found a very dirty hack, i basically set the first click to play and then instantly stop the audio, the gaze hover then works as its already been initiated.